# How do I know if a matrix is diagonalizable by congruence?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, bilinear-form, sesquilinear-forms

Let V be a [unitary space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) over $\mathbb{C}^n$ with an orthonormal basis $K$.
Let $A: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a [sesquilinear form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form).

If there exists a basis $B$ in $V$ such that $[A]_B$ is diagonal, what does that mean for the matrix $[A]_K$? What are the necessary conditions for $B$ to exist? And is there a general algorithm to find one?

I know that if $[A]_K$ is [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix), or more generally [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix), there [always exists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_diagonalization) an orthonormal base $B$ which satisfies this. But what if $[A]_K$ isn't normal?

Just to be clear, I'm asking about the *diagonalization by congruence*, rather than by similarity. The diagonal matrix $[A]_B$ has to meet this condition:
$$ [A]_K = R^+ \; [A]_B \; R, $$
where $R$ is a regular matrix and $R^+$ its [conjugate transpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).

Answer (score -1):

If $[A]_B$ is diagonalisable by congruence, of course $[A]_K$ is also diagonalisable by congruence, because the matrices of a sequilinear form are related by congruences.

So, the basic question is, when is a complex square matrix diagonalisable by congruence? Note that this is not always possible. E.g. if $e_1e_2^T=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}$ is diagonalisable by congruence, there will exist an invertible $P$ and some $z\ne 0$ such that
$$
(P^\ast e_1)(P^\ast e_2)^\ast=P^\ast e_1e_2^TP=\pmatrix{z\\ &0}=ze_1e_1^T\ne0,
$$
meaning that both $P^\ast e_1$ and $P^\ast e_2$ are scalar multiples of $e_1$. But this is impossible because $P$ is invertible. Thus $e_1e_2^T$ is not diagonalisable by congruence.

In general, let $M=H_1+iH_2$, where $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hermitian. Then $M$ diagonalisable by congruence if and only if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are simultaneously diagonalisable by congruence.

Here is a known result. When at least one of $H_1$ and $H_2$ is nonsingular, they are simultaneously diagonalisable by congruence (and hence $M$ is diagonalisable by congruence) if and only if $H_k^{-1}H_{3-k}$ is *similar* to a real diagonal matrix. For details, see the section on "Congruence and simultaneous diagonalization" or more specifically, theorem 4.5.15 of Horn and Johnson, *Matrix Analysis*, first edition, 1985, p.228 (theorem or page numbers may be different in the second edition).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure how the first paragraph is relevant, since I'm not asking for $[A]_B$ to be diagonalizable, but *diagonal*, so the question really is about the diagonalizability of $[A]_K$, trivially so.

Also, I don't understand what $H_k$ and $H_{3-k}$ are. I'll look into Congruence and simultaneous diagonalization, but the answer should be clear on its own.

Comment: @m93a (1) Diagonal matrices are diagonalisable (because they are already diagonal). So, if $[A]_B$ is **diagonal**, then $[A]_K$ is **diagonalisable** by congruence. (2) $H_k^{-1}H_{3-k}$ is $H_1^{-1}H_2$ (when $k=1$) or $H_2^{-1}H_1$ (when $k=2$), depending on which $H_k$ is invertible.